# set value button to a text box then move to the next one jquery

Tags: jquery, button, textbox

I have two buttons and two text fields.

I want to click on a button that will get its value button and then set it as value of the text field and then move to the other text.

I have already made the value fill up but I don't know how to move to the next textbox here is the code I can make the button value on the first textbox and not on the second one

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function() {
    var btnv = this.value;
    $('#test1').val(this.value);
}); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page">
<div data-role="content">
<div>
<input type="text" id="test1" value="" disabled >
<input type="text" id="test2" value="" disabled>
<button id="btn1" value="V">bn1</button>
<button id="btn2" value="R" >bn2</button>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, in your click event handler for the button add the following code.

```
$(this).next("input[type=text]").focus();
```

Comment: thank you for you answer in my case I am using JQuery